# How should optional or empty values be handled in Semantic Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am setting up some templates for a Semantic Mediawiki implementation. Template params are being fed into annotations. However, the values are optional; there's not always going to be a value in every field. This causes trouble with some data types. Specifically, if I have

```
{{#set:
| Has phone={{{phone}}}
}}
```

I will get an error of the form `URIs of the form *** are not allowed` where *** is either `{{{phone}}}` or whatever default value I try to drop in there. It seems impossible for datatypes like phone or email to be empty. I cannot figure out how to support empty values for these fields in my templates. What is the correct pattern to use for null values in SMW annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [default-value feature](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Default_values) of template parameters, but give it a blank default value:

```
{{#set:
| Has phone={{{phone|}}}
}}
```

(*Updated:*) Or if you need to prevent it setting anything at all, wrap it in a conditional:

```
{{#if: {{{phone|}}}
| {{#set: Has phone={{{phone}}} }}
}}
```

Comment: This does not work for annotations with the dataType phone. An empty string is an invalid phone number and generates an error.

Comment: @Topsy: sorry, missed that. I've updated my answer. :)

Comment: Seems so awkward, but I'm just getting used to MW and SMW... If that's how it's done, then so be it. Thank you. Also, to clarify: this solutions requires the ParserFunctions extension.

Comment: Yep, it does require ParserFunctions. And it is awkward, but really usually only done in a template that defines an entity, so it's not too bad. :)